# Compare Function of Collections.sort Expected a Value of Type Int in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In the code:

```
Collections.sort(activities, Comparator<ResolveInfo> {
    fun compare(a: ResolveInfo, b: ResolveInfo): Int {
        var pm = activity!!.packageManager
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(a.loadLabel(pm).toString(), b.loadLabel(pm).toString())
        }
    })
```

The compiler is telling me "Type Mismatch: Required Int."

But isn't it returning an int?

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution is quite simple - in order to create an object of some interface class a keyword `object` is required before `Comparator` as below:

```
Collections.sort(activities, object: Comparator<ResolveInfo> {
    fun compare(a: ResolveInfo, b: ResolveInfo): Int {
        var pm = activity!!.packageManager
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(a.loadLabel(pm).toString(), b.loadLabel(pm).toString())
        }
    })
```

For more information please check [Object Expressions and Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)

Comment: I guess that kind of takes the place of new in Java. Thank you. :)